# How to make function wait to return after getResult from SQL Statement is available?

Tags: sql, flash, apache-flex, sqlite, air

I'm just trying to make a simple function that will return all the data from my SQLITE database as an array. But it looks like when my function is returning the array, the SQL statement is actually still executing... so it's empty... Does anyone have a suggestion? Or am I just going about this whole thing wrong.

I know I could just have the event listener functions outside this function, and they could then set the data. But i'm trying to make a AS3 Class that holds all my SQL functions, and It would be nice to have everything for this particular function just in one function, so it can return an array to me.

```
 public function getFavsGamesArray():Array
                {
                    getFavsArraySql.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, res);
                    getFavsArraySql.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, error);

                    getFavsArraySql.text = "SELECT * FROM favGames";
                    getFavsArraySql.execute();

                    var favsArr:Array = new Array();

                    function res(e:SQLEvent):void
                    {
                        trace("sql good!");
                        favsArr=getFavsArraySql.getResult().data;
                    }

                    function error(e:SQLEvent):void
                    {
                        trace("sql error!");

                    }

                    trace(favsArr);

                    return favsArr;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question, Instead of expecting getFavsGamesArray() to actually return the results from an asynchronous event (which it likely never will), consider passing a function (as an argument) to call within your res() function that would then process the data.

In your SQL helper class, we'll call it SQLHelper.as:

```
private var processResultsFun:Function;

public function getFavsGamesArray(callBackFun:Function):void
{ 
    processResultsFun = callBackFun;
    ...

} //Do not return array, instead leave it void

function res(e:SQLEvent):void
{
    trace("sql good!");
    if(processResultsFun != null) 
    {
        processResultsFun(getFavsArraySql.getResult().data);

    }
}
```

In the class(es) that call your SQL helper class:

```
function processRows(results:Array):void {
    //Make sure this function has an Array argument
    //By the time this is called you should have some results
}
...

SQLHelper.getFavsGamesArray(processRows);
```

You can optionally pass an error handling function as well.

Comment: This solution works great! Just the kinda work around I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your task is asynchronous.

`favsArr`is a temporary variable, and you return its value directly when `getFavsGamesArray` completes.  At that time, the value will always be `null`, because the listener methods are called only after the SQL statement is complete - which will be at some time in the future.

**You need some way to delay everything you are going to do with the return value, until it actually exists.**

The best way to do it is to dispatch your own custom event, and add the value as a field to the event object, or to add a listener method outside of your SQL class directly to the `SQLStatement` - and have it do stuff with `event.target.getResult().data`.  That way you can always be sure the value exists, when processing occurs, and you keep your SQL behavior decoupled from everything on the outside.

I would also strongly encourage you not to declare your event listeners inside functions like this: You can't clean up these listeners after the SQL statements completes!

True: Declaring a function inside a function makes it temporary.  That is, it exists only for the scope of your function, and it is garbage collected when it's no longer needed - just like temporary variables. But "it is no longer needed" does not apply if you use it as an event listener! The only reason this works at all is that you don't use [weak references](http://dispatchevent.org/mims/creating-weak-references-in-as3/) - if you did, the functions *would* be garbage collected before they are even called.  Since you don't, the listeners will execute.  But then you can't remove them without a reference!  They continue to exist, as will the SQL statement, even if you set its references to `null` - and you've successfully created a [memory leak](http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3).  Not a bad one, probably, but still...

If you really want to encapsulate your SQL behavior, that is a good thing.  Just consider moving *each SQL statement* to a dedicated class, instead of creating one giant SQLHelper, and having your listener methods declared as member functions - it is much easier to prevent memory leaks and side effects, if you keep references to everything, and you can use these in a `destroy` method to clean up properly.

Comment: I forgot to mention memory management in my answer, and you explained it quite well. +1up